# Look for a file name from a set of files (in CMD)

Tags: for-loop, cmd, command-line, command, window

I would like to find a video file name in a folder (it has ~1000 files) using Windows command line. But... there is a problem, I do not remember the video file name, I have some clues: The video was created between **2019/02/01** to **2019/05/31** (format: Year/Month/Day) and the hour was between **09:00:00** to **13:00:00** (format: Hour/Minute/Second).

The format about this video file name is: **VID_YEARMONTHDAY_HOURMINUTESECOND.3gp** , example: VID_20190226_155112.3gp . Sometimes the video file name could has this format: **VID_YEARMONTHDAY_HOURMINUTESECOND WORDS.3gp** , example: VID_20190226_155112 EJEMPLO1.3gp

I read **for** command from Microsoft Docs and I built this:

```
for %A in (VID_201902* VID_201903* VID_201904* VID_201905*) do (for %B in (090000,1,130000) do (if %A:~0,19%==%A:~0,13%%B% echo %A%))
```

I do not know why it does not work. I will explain the code: I get set of files from February to May, a nested for goes from 090000 to 130000 (it represents the hour) then I compare between actual file name %A AND file name %A with hour %B, because as I told I want hours between 09:00:00 to 13:00:00. Finally if my condition is accomplished I show video file name (%A).

I know that the code is not efficient. I ask: **Why doesn't the code work?**

Comment: You're confusing `for` meta-variables with normal environment variables: the former look like `%A`, `%B` and don't support sub-string expansion (like `~0,19`); the latter look like `%A%`, `%VAR%` and do support something like `%VAR:~0,19%`. And the second loop should be `for /L`...

Comment: What about a totally different approach: `dir /B /A:-D "VID_*.3gp" | findstr /I /R /C:"^VID_20190[2-5][0-3][0-9]_09[0-5][0-9][0-5][0-9]" /C:"^VID_20190[2-5][0-3][0-9]_1[0-3][0-5][0-9][0-5][0-9]"`...

Comment: @aschipfl Thanks, your code worked perfectly and I found the video file name that I was looking for. About **your code**: **1.** "|" pipe symbol, I do not know what it does, it seems an "or" logical operator. **2.** [number-number], example: [2-5], is it a range of values?. **3** What does "^" mean?

Comment: @aschipfl About **my code**... I would like to fix it. What about this: `for %A in (VID_201902* VID_201903* VID_201904* VID_201905*) do (for /L %B in (090000,1,130000) do (envVar=%A if %envVar:~0,19%==%envVar:~0,13%%B echo %envVar%))` . The code does not work, it is only an idea, because I do not know how to declare a enviroment variable. **Could this idea work?** **NOTE**: "envVar" is an environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

To find the desired video files I would go for a totally different approach:

```cmd
dir /B /A:-D "VID_*.3gp" | findstr /I /R /C:"^VID_20190[2-5][0-3][0-9]_09[0-5][0-9][0-5][0-9]" /C:"^VID_20190[2-5][0-3][0-9]_1[0-2][0-5][0-9][0-5][0-9]" /C:"^VID_20190[2-5][0-3][0-9]_130000"
```

The [`dir` command](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) returns all files (`/A:-D`) whose names begin with `VID_` and end with `.3gp` as a bare list (`/B`) of file names, so no extra information is output. This list is [piped (`|`)](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) into the [`findstr` command](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html), which has got three case-insensitive (`/I`) search expressions (like regular expressions, `/R`, although `findstr` does not really support true regular expressions but only a tiny excerpt of them) defined, all of which cover the beginning (`^`) of the file name (`VID_`), the specified date range (Feb. to May 2019), `_` and:

- to cover time range 09:00:00 to 09:59:59: `^VID_20190[2-5][0-3][0-9]_09[0-5][0-9][0-5][0-9]`;
- to cover time range 10:00:00 to 12:59:59: `^VID_20190[2-5][0-3][0-9]_1[0-2][0-5][0-9][0-5][0-9]`;
- to cover the time 13:00:00: `^VID_20190[2-5][0-3][0-9]_130000`;

---

Concerning your code: you are confusing [`for`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) meta-variables with normal [environment variables](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html); the former look like `%A`, `%B` and do not support [sub-string expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html) (like `~0,19`); the latter look like `%A%`, `%VAR%`, can be defined by [`set`](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html) and do support something like `%VAR:~0,19%`. And the second loop should be `for /L`, by the way.

I would first extend the [file name patterns](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-wildcards.html) a bit and use something like `VID_201902??_*.3gp` rather than `VID_201902*`, but this of course depends on what file names may actually occur.

I also would reduce the string portion to compare by [`if`](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html), because the first 13 characters of the left and the right expression are always equal, so they could be removed to get `if "%VAR:~14,6%"=="%B"` (let me recommend to use [quotation](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) for this string comparison).

Another problem is the value `090000` in `for /L %B in (090000,1,130000) do`, which is going to be treated as an octal value rather than a decimal one due to the leading `0` (see [`set`](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)). You could state `90000` instead and add a leading zero to `%B` later then when required though.

Since the `for /L` loop has to iterate 40001 times for each file, your code will be slow. As a better alternative, you could do `for /L %B in (9,1,13) do` and just compare the hour value, unless it is `13`, where only `130000` is acceptable according to your specifications.

---

You are coming closer to a working variant in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58193653/look-for-a-file-name-from-a-set-of-files-in-cmd/58234714#comment102832152_58193653) of yours, but it lacks of [delayed variable expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html), which is required when a variable is written and read within the same line or (parenthesised) block of code.

Anyway, to put all of the above together, the fixed code would be something like this, given that the Command Prompt has been started by `cmd /V:ON` before in order to enable delayed expansion:

```cmd
for %A in ("VID_201902??_*.3gp" "VID_201903??_*.3gp" "VID_201904??_*.3gp" "VID_201905??_*.3gp") do @(set "STR=%~A" & for /L %B in (9,1,13) do @(set "NUM=%B" & (if !NUM! lss 10 set "NUM=0!NUM!") & if !NUM! lss 13 (if "!STR:~13,2!"=="!NUM!" echo/!STR!) else if "!STR:~13,6!"=="130000" echo/!STR!))
```

The same code would look like this in a batch script:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%A in ("VID_201902??_*.3gp" "VID_201903??_*.3gp" "VID_201904??_*.3gp" "VID_201905??_*.3gp") do (
    set "STR=%%~A"
    for /L %%B in (9,1,13) do (
        set "NUM=%%B"
        if !NUM! lss 10 set "NUM=0!NUM!"
        if !NUM! lss 13 (if "!STR:~13,2!"=="!NUM!" echo/!STR!) else if "!STR:~13,6!"=="130000" echo/!STR!
    )
)
endlocal
```